# PHP Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference

Tags: php

Here's the code in question. It started looking like this:

```
$comments_by_type = &separate_comments(get_comments('status=approve&post_id=' . $id));  
return count($comments_by_type['comment']);
```

I removed the & signs per other posts I have seen but it didn't help.

```
$comments_by_type = separate_comments(get_comments('status=approve post_id=' . $id));
return count($comments_by_type['comment']);
```

Comment: the arguments for `separate_comments` are being passed by-reference as `function separate_comments(&$comments)`.  You would need to assign `get_comments` to a variable. `$comments = get_comments('status=approve&post_id=' . $id);` Then `separate_comments($comments);`

Comment: I tried your suggestion:                                                                                                      $comments_by_type = (get_comments('status=approve&post_id=' . $id)); separate_comments($comments); return count($comments_by_type['comment']);                                                                                     it didn't work.....thanks for trying.

Comment: You passed the wrong variable name to `separate_comments` as you never defined `$comments`, please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by the arguments for `separate_comments` being passed by-reference. Source: `function separate_comments(&$comments)`. This means passing a function as an argument is restricted.

To resolve the issue you need to assign the `get_comments` function results to a variable.

```
$comments = get_comments('status=approve&post_id=' . $id);
$comments_by_type = separate_comments($comments);
return count($comments_by_type['comment']);
```